# Javafx FXML - How to make GridPane the same height as the window?

Tags: javafx, fxml

The intended outcome is that the element at (0,0) should resize to fill up the empty space around the GridPane. I have looked at other questions similar to this and the answers have not worked - I am trying to make the GridPane the same height as the VBox that is inside of. It works horizontally using hrow="always", but using vgrow="always" has not had the same affect.
I have coloured the VBox that the GridPane is within a different colour, so it is clear that the VBox is taking up the height of the stage, and therefore the GridPane is the issue here. How could I stretch the vertical height similar to the horizontal width?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.SubScene?>
<?import javafx.scene.Group?>

<VBox
    fx:controller="Controller" 
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
    styleClass="root" >
    
    <MenuBar>
        <menus>
            <Menu text="File">
                <items>
                    <MenuItem text="New" />
                    <MenuItem text="Save" />
                    <MenuItem text="Load" />
                </items>
            </Menu>
        </menus>
    </MenuBar>
    
    <GridPane hgap="10" vgap="10">
    
        <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints vgrow="ALWAYS" />
        </rowConstraints>
        
        <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" />
        </columnConstraints>
    
        <gridLinesVisible>true</gridLinesVisible>
        
        <SubScene
            GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0"
            GridPane.rowSpan="6">
            
            <root>
            <Group />
            </root>
            
        </SubScene>
            
        <Button text="Add"
            GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            
        <Button text="Edit"
            GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            
        <Button text="Delete"
            GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            
        <ScrollPane 
            GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"
            GridPane.columnSpan="3" />
            
        <Label text="Speed"
            GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            
        <Slider
            GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" 
            GridPane.columnSpan="2" />
            
        <Label text="Gravity"
            GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            
        <TextField
            GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3" 
            GridPane.columnSpan="2" />
            
        <HBox
            GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
            <Button text="&lt;&lt;" />
            <Button text="&lt;" />
        </HBox>
        
        <Text text="0.00" 
            GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
        
        <HBox
            GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
            <Button text="&gt;" />
            <Button text="&gt;&gt;" />
        </HBox>
        
        <Button text="Start" 
            GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
        
    </GridPane>
    
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@style.css" />
    </stylesheets>  

</VBox>
```

[image]

Comment: Either add `VBox.vgrow = “NEVER”` to the menu and `VBox.vgrow=“ALWAYS”` to the grid pane, or (perhaps better) replace the `VBox` with a `BorderPane` and put the menu in the top and the grid pane in the center.

Comment: Thank you, the BorderPane worked perfectly!