# javafx fxml - How to make Subscene the same area as the GridPane cell?

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have a program that will have a 2D section on the right, and a 3D section on the left. I use a GridPane to have all of the buttons and other stuff laid out, and then the 3D SubScene takes up the entire first column of the GridPane. 
However, I am only able to set the size of the SubScene using hard-coded values, but I would like the SubScene to take up the entire width and height of the GridPane cells that it is inside of. Is there a way to do this? 
Note: The GridPane's first column (where the subscene is) changes size when the window is resized, hence why I cannot just hard code the values.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.SubScene?>
<?import javafx.scene.Group?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Box?>
<?import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera?>

<BorderPane fx:controller="Controller"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" styleClass="root">

    <top>
        <MenuBar>
            <menus>
                <Menu text="File">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem text="New"
                            onAction="#handleNewSimulationAction" />
                        <MenuItem text="Save"
                            onAction="#handleSaveSimulationAction" />
                        <MenuItem text="Load"
                            onAction="#handleLoadSimulationAction" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
            </menus>
        </MenuBar>
    </top>

    <center>
        <GridPane hgap="10" vgap="10">

            <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints vgrow="NEVER" />
                <RowConstraints vgrow="ALWAYS" />
            </rowConstraints>

            <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            </columnConstraints>

            <gridLinesVisible>true</gridLinesVisible>

            <SubScene fx:id="subscene" width="50" height="50"
                GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.rowSpan="6">

                <root>
                    <Region />
                </root>

            </SubScene>

            <Button text="Add" GridPane.columnIndex="1"
                GridPane.rowIndex="0" onAction="#handleAddAction" />

            <Button text="Edit" GridPane.columnIndex="2"
                GridPane.rowIndex="0" onAction="#handleEditAction" />

            <Button text="Delete" GridPane.columnIndex="3"
                GridPane.rowIndex="0" onAction="#handleDeleteAction" />

            <ScrollPane GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"
                GridPane.columnSpan="3" />

            <Label text="Speed" GridPane.columnIndex="1"
                GridPane.rowIndex="2" />

            <Slider GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2"
                GridPane.columnSpan="2" />

            <Label text="Gravity" GridPane.columnIndex="1"
                GridPane.rowIndex="3" />

            <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3"
                GridPane.columnSpan="2" />

            <HBox GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                <Button text="&lt;&lt;" onAction="#handleQuickRewindAction" />
                <Button text="&lt;" onAction="#handleRewindAction" />
            </HBox>

            <Text text="0.00" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />

            <HBox GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                <Button text="&gt;" onAction="#handleFastForwardAction" />
                <Button text="&gt;&gt;"
                    onAction="#handleQuickFastForwardAction" />
            </HBox>

            <Button text="Start" GridPane.columnIndex="2"
                GridPane.rowIndex="5" onAction="#handlePauseAction" />

        </GridPane>
    </center>

    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@style.css" />
    </stylesheets>

</BorderPane>
```

The grey square in the image is the SubScene, with hard coded values so that it is visible. If values for the width and height are not hardcoded, it will simply not appear on the screen.
[image]

Comment: Perhaps I could have a subscene on the left, then the GridPane on the right using a HBox, but then the subscene would need to take up the area of the HBox... any thoughts?

Comment: hmm ... how is this different from your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74172106/javafx-fxml-how-to-make-gridpane-the-same-height-as-the-window? at the end of the day you have to learn all about Layouts, imo

Comment: See also [`LayoutDemo`](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/tree/master/apps/toys/LayoutDemo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, there may be other ways as well, but this is my take on this issue :).

I would like to recommend you to rethink about the layout implementation. I think it would be better to keep the right side part in its own gridPane and you primarily deal with only 2 sections (center- subScene and right-  form layout). That way you don't unneccesarily mess with layout by keeping too many eggs in one basket.

And regarding the `SubScene`, it does not fit in any of the standard layouts behavior (like no min/pref/max sizes). It pretty much has the same features as Shape, where you need to explicity set the width/height when required.

So for that, you need to do some explicit calculations to determine the width/height of the `SubScene` whenever the main scene size is changed.

Below is the quick demo for changes to your code: (*If your window is a TRANSPARENT stage, then in the calculations, you may need to consider the window header size as well*)

[image]

**FXML Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.SubScene?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<BorderPane fx:id="mainLayout" fx:controller="Controller" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            styleClass="root">
    <top>
        <MenuBar fx:id="menuBar">
            <menus>
                <Menu text="File">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem text="New"
                                  onAction="#handleNewSimulationAction"/>
                        <MenuItem text="Save"
                                  onAction="#handleSaveSimulationAction"/>
                        <MenuItem text="Load"
                                  onAction="#handleLoadSimulationAction"/>
                    </items>
                </Menu>
            </menus>
        </MenuBar>
    </top>
    <right>
        <GridPane fx:id="sideLayout" hgap="10" vgap="10">
            <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints vgrow="NEVER"/>
                <RowConstraints vgrow="ALWAYS"/>
            </rowConstraints>
            <gridLinesVisible>true</gridLinesVisible>
            <padding>
                <Insets left="10"/>
            </padding>
            <Button text="Add" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" onAction="#handleAddAction"
                    prefWidth="-1" minWidth="-Infinity"/>
            <Button text="Edit" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0"
                    onAction="#handleEditAction" prefWidth="-1" minWidth="-Infinity"/>
            <Button text="Delete" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="0"
                    onAction="#handleDeleteAction" prefWidth="-1" minWidth="-Infinity"/>

            <ScrollPane GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="3"/>

            <Label text="Speed" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
            <StackPane GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.columnSpan="2"/>

            <Label text="Gravity" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="3"/>
            <StackPane GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" GridPane.columnSpan="2"/>

            <HBox GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                <Button text="&lt;&lt;" onAction="#handleQuickRewindAction" prefWidth="-1"
                        minWidth="-Infinity"/>
                <Button text="&lt;" onAction="#handleRewindAction" prefWidth="-1" minWidth="-Infinity"/>
            </HBox>
            <Text text="0.00" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4"/>
            <HBox GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                <Button text="&gt;" onAction="#handleFastForwardAction" prefWidth="-1"
                        minWidth="-Infinity"/>
                <Button text="&gt;&gt;"
                        onAction="#handleQuickFastForwardAction" prefWidth="-1" minWidth="-Infinity"/>
            </HBox>

            <Button text="Start" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5"
                    onAction="#handlePauseAction" prefWidth="-1" minWidth="-Infinity"/>
        </GridPane>
    </right>
    <center>
        <SubScene fx:id="subscene">
            <root>
                <StackPane style="-fx-background-color:yellow;-fx-border-width:1px;-fx-border-color:red;">
                    <Label text="Sub Scene" style="-fx-font-size:16px;"/>
                </StackPane>
            </root>
        </SubScene>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

**Controller code:**

```
@FXML
private MenuBar menuBar;

@FXML
private SubScene subscene;

@FXML
private GridPane sideLayout;

@FXML
public void initialize() {
    subscene.sceneProperty().addListener((ob, ol, scene) -> {
        scene.heightProperty().addListener((obs, old, height) -> updateHeight());
        scene.widthProperty().addListener((obs, old, width) -> updateWidth());
    });
    sideLayout.heightProperty().addListener((obs, old, height) -> updateHeight());
    sideLayout.widthProperty().addListener((obs, old, width) -> updateWidth());
}

private void updateHeight() {
    double sceneHeight = subscene.getScene().getHeight();
    subscene.setHeight(sceneHeight - menuBar.getHeight());
}

private void updateWidth() {
    double sceneWidth = subscene.getScene().getWidth();
    subscene.setWidth(sceneWidth - sideLayout.getWidth());
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked! However, if I include the slider and textfield from my original question it adds random whitespace on the left of the window? I see you replaced them with StackPanes... how would I implement the slider and textfield?

Comment: I too noticed that and didn't focused much on it and replaced it with StackPane. Looks definitely like an existing issue in JavaFX. Try playing with BorderPane-GridPane-Slider-Textfield combination layouts and see if it is reproducible.